# Too much Android?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-crossover

Here's a screenshot I took about 10 seconds ago:

[image: Android!]

Isn't it time to make another site or direct such questions (with the [android] tag) to [the Android Stack Exchange site](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour)??

Comment: "make another site" Why even have tags then? "direct ... to Android StackExchange" No because these are programming questions.

Comment: While we're at it, we should make separate sites for [Java, JavaScript, C# and php](http://stackoverflow.com/tags), too. Or _not_.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree about a site for C#...

Answer (score 17):

Right...where to start...

First, Android Enthusiasts is about...*enthusiasts.*  You can be a programmer and an enthusiast, but if you have a programming question, [the standing advice is to ask it on Stack Overflow.](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Next, there are about ~679K questions in [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).  This compares to the ~866K questions in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or the ~802K questions in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23).  Even though I can be sure that there's *some* overlap with Java and Android, the fact of the matter is that there's comparably not a lot of questions in Android.

To put it in better perspective:  there are ~9530K (or ~9.5M if you prefer) questions on Stack Overflow.  Android only takes up **7%** of all questions on the site.

So no, I don't think that breaking that up would be a good idea.  I don't think it's too big.  I doubt it makes sense to especially when there are established experts *here* who are willing to answer the questions.  Further to that, perhaps the question isn't scoped to just Android - maybe it's Java related in nature?  Why exclude that subset of experts because they don't program Android?

Comment: And ~864K questions in [tag:JavaScript]. Don't leave out the [second largest tag, now ;-)](http://stackoverflow.com/tags)

Answer (score 11):

Odd. My front page has 0 android questions on it...

I have set up favorite tags. I don't include Android. You can do this too. Below the community bulletin is where your favorites exist. Click the edit button.

[image: Favorite Tags]

Your selection of favorite (and ignored) tags influences what appears on the front page when you are logged in. If you have no interest in android questions, don't favorite that tag.

---

Regarding your suggestion for a separate site. There is an [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) site, but the first bullet in their ["What is off topic here..."](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is:

> - Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)

Splitting off Android programming questions because there are "too many", means that we would probably need to consider doing it for several more popular [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). There are 4 tags that are more popular: java, javascript, c# and php. jQuery is not far behind. Do we gut Stack Overflow by splitting all of these? I don't believe that's a good idea.

Instead, focus on customizing what tags you care about (and don't care about). That will change what you see on your front page and remove the questions you have no interest in from your view.

Comment: we can make sub-sites like php.stackovrflow.com and send relevant questions there automatically...

Comment: @RahulBasu we *could*, but *why would we*?

Comment: @Rahul2001 That's called a tag.